# In Firestore, how can I query items created within a date range and order by a different field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a query for "top posts of the last week/month/year". I thought it would be simple, but I'm running into limitations with Firestore's querying rules.

Here's the query I'd ideally like to run:

```
db
  .collection(MY_COLLECTION)
  .where('created', '>', new Date(fromDate))
  .orderBy('score', 'desc')
```

That gives me this error:

> FirebaseError: Invalid query. You have a where filter with an
>   inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) on field 'created' and so you must also
>   use 'created' as your first Query.orderBy(), but your first
>   Query.orderBy() is on field 'score' instead.

Is there a known strategy or workaround for these types of queries?

Comment: Currently my only idea is to have a daily cron job that sets fields `isWithinWeek`, `isWithinMonth` and `isWithinYear` on all posts so that I can use that as an equality filter. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error you are getting, you should first order by the `created` field, as follows:

```
db
  .collection(MY_COLLECTION)
  .where('created', '>', new Date(fromDate))
  .orderBy('created', 'desc')
  .orderBy('score', 'desc')
```

This is indicated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data):

> If you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=),
>   your first ordering must be on the same field.

Note that you will need to create an index for this query. For that, just run the query once and in the error message that you will get you will find the URL to call in order to create the index.

---

If you want to query for all documents between two dates, you can use a query like:

```
db
  .collection(MY_COLLECTION)
  .where('created', '>', new Date(fromDate))
  .where('created', '<=', new Date(toDate))
  .orderBy('created', 'desc')
  .orderBy('score', 'desc')
```

Comment: Great answer Renaud. For Gus: this indeed means you'll get the results ordered on the value of the `created` field first, which is probably not what you want. So you'll have to resort them in your application code to be on score.

Comment: Thanks for adding this extra info Frank! @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this doesn't solve my problem because I need to sort by score. I can't just do that in the application code because there are potentially thousands of posts in the time period. I left it off in the query code but I also have a limit clause.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen and Renaud I understand that this is a limitation of how indexes work, but I thought it would be a very common requirement and one that already has some best practice approaches. Is there anything else you could point me to or is my comment on the original question the best way to achieve this? Thanks :)

Comment: The best way to achieve it is to do the filtering in the query, and then reorder the results in the client. If the client can load data for thousands of posts over the network, it can definitely also sort that data in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry I think I phrased my comment poorly. I am specifically NOT wanting to query thousands of posts, I'm looking for a solution to only get say 20 at a time. It seems I will need to run a cron job that sets/unsets flags like `isWithinWeek` on the posts so that I can compare equality rather than range.